# Generating Token (JWT) in Spring

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, auth0, spring-rest

I am building my first Spring REST API. I have made a registration and login, but it is time to secure these processes. I store users informations and passwords (hashed) in a database.

I did this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/register","/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .csrf().disable();             
}
```

It gives everybody permission to access login/register and blocks any other request. Now I want to use JWT and keep access to a certain functions only for logged in users.  Is there an easy way to do it? Maybe someone has a good materials on it? I would be very thankful.

PS. I have followed this tutorial [here](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/), and I've ended up being able to create and pass token, but I think it "overrides" my service implementation, returns empty response (token in header) and has hard coded credentials. I want to sent to user my custom response + token in header.

Comment: The tutorial you've followed has all that you need. You could send your custom response as you do without JWT, token added to header by filter, like it shown in tutorial: `.addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`
 and 
`.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`

Comment: Doing this with Auth0 should be easy to achieve. Please can I recommend that you take a look at this sample - https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-sample  for securing an API.  If instead, you wish to secure an MVC App (has a UI and Login page) then this one - https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-mvc-sample.  Disclaimer - I wrote the libraries and samples. Feel free to leave me messages if you run into any difficulties with setup.